# How to change height of the Export Dialogue box of BIRT frameset

Tags: javascript, css, birt

I am working on BIRT and want to modify UI for the export dialogue box. As we click on export report button, dialogue box appears in middle of the frameset and I want it to appear on top. I tried to modify some JS files of the BIRT but din get anything. Can someone help for this.

Comment: You need to share enough code to reproduce the situation .... HTML and CSS

Comment: I am not able to get the exact code of HTML and CSS from BIRT frameset.